# Selenium, JS -- Why Date decrease and increase for days and months?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, testing

When I use selenium (with Python) to fill input dates, days are diminished and months increased.

I use this code to fill the input:

```
self.selenium.execute_script("document.getElementById('startDateLS').valueAsDate = new Date(2017, 11, 02);")
self.selenium.execute_script("document.getElementById('endDateLS').valueAsDate = new Date(2017, 11, 22);")
```

but the result is this:

[input dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D40A9.png)

Do you know why?

Comment: months start from `0` to `11`.

Comment: Use a string: `new Date('2017-11-02')`

Comment: Why `02`? If it's an integer, it's more normal to use `2`.

Comment: @FlorentB. thanks you, it's working..